# Why is my reverse string missing commas? (Freecodecamp beginners' algorithms ex.1)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am doing the Freecodecamp algorithm challenges, as I am new to programming. The problem statement is as follows:

> Reverse the provided string. You may need to turn the string into an array before you can reverse it. Your result must be a string.

I've picked up the suggestion of turning the string into an array, but I have some problems with the output. Here's my implementation:

```
 function reverseString(str) {
   var myAr =  str.split("");
   newString = myAr.reverse().toString().replace(/,/g,"");
   return newString;
 }
```

This works fine for some strings, like `hello world`, but **doesn't work for strings with commas** e.g. `hello, world!`.

My expected output is `!dlrow ,olleh` but I get `!dlrow olleh`.

Why is my code failing? What can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your code won't work with strings that contain a `,` character, SO is not really about this kind of questions. If you have a specific issue with your code clearly state what you tried, what the problem you are trying to solve is, what isn't working and what you would expect instead.

Comment: Add the language tag as well, code not seems to be related to algorithms at all, as you are using the built-in functions instead of building the algorithm of your own.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, though a bit harsh and with downgrade, but I somehow used to that kind of treatment on stackoverflow, I am just happy you took your time to reply. Thank you so much! The problem is as follows: "Reverse the provided string.You may need to turn the string into an array before you can reverse it. Your result must be a string." I am not able to figure out problems on my own, that's why I ask you to help me out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the response is not harsh (even though the SO attitude of some users is really harsh, but I digress). Your question does not fit the format of the site, it's written without context, doesn't show the results you are expecting and it is similar to questions asking for help with homework *or* a code review question (which is also OT). In summary, it is very low quality so it attracted downvotes.

Comment: I did not mean to make you feel uncomfortable, I just generally think stackoverflow is not a friendly place for beginners and that's a shame. I will try to add context, possible test and result in the next question I post. Thanks Andrea, actually, the fact, that you told that it won't work with the ',' character really helped me. Do you know why is so and how can I fix it?  P.S.: what's OT?

Comment: Hint: use `Array.prototype.join` instead of `toString` ... `replace`.  It would be better to research how to use it than relying on an answer here. ( PS OT = "off topic".)

Comment: Thanks, Traktor53. You're awesome. ;)

Comment: I do not feel uncomfortable, I was just explaining why the quality of your question doesn't really fit on this site. Don't wait until the next one, you can improve this one already! :) SO is OK for beginners but they need to show a research effort and moreover they have to clearly state what the problem is. I'll now propose an edit on your Q to illustrate what you can improve in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, the 'inverse' of [`String.split("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is [`Array.join("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which avoids issues when the input string contains commas.

Why does `myAr.reverse().toString().replace(/,/g,"")` cause issues with commas? Let's see what happens when we supply a string with a comma:

```
reverseString('one, two'); // returns "owt eno" - missing the comma
```

1. You first split this string into an array of characters:

   ```
   myAr = str.split(""); // evaluates to ["o", "n", "e", ",", " ", "t", "w", "o"]
   ```
2. Then, you reverse the array:

   ```
   myAr.reverse() // evaluates to ["o", "w", "t", " ", ",", "e", "n", "o"]
   ```
3. Next, you convert the reversed array to a string:

   ```
   myAr.reverse().toString() // evaluates to "o,w,t, ,,,e,n,o"
   ```
4. And finally, you remove all commas:

   ```
   myAr.reverse().toString().replace(/,/g,""); // evaluates to "owt eno"
   ```

You see that converting an array to a string (step 3) equals concatenating all elements with commas. It is identical to performing `array.join(",")`. Now, by removing all commas (in step 4) from that string you unfortunately also remove those commas that where part of the input. There is no way to distinguish a "genuine" comma from one that has been introduced by joining the array (in step 3).

I would also suggest a few naming changes and either declaring the currently global variable `newString` as a local variable using `var` or immediately returning it without introducing a new variable at all:

```js
function reverseString(string) {
  var chars = string.split("");
  return chars.reverse().join("");
}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

If you want to avoid using the built-in `Array.reverse` function, have a look at the answers to this question: [reverse-string-in-javascript-without-using-reverse](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133769/reverse-string-in-javascript-without-using-reverse)

Comment: Nice answer. It also works for the proposed edit that I did at the Q and is still in review. :) I would also add that, given the assignment, still using `.reverse` is a little bit like cheating. OP might want to implement the reverse process iteratively or recursively. That would be a better learning experience, IMHO.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Nice edit, too. I'll point OP to one of the many string reversal questions that feature answers without `reverse`,

Comment: AndreaLazzarotto @le_m You two made my day, I can't express how nice it is from both of you. Thanks a ton! I can't upvote yet, but I definitely send you kudos!

Comment: @Margot good. As a first step I suggest that you sift through your old questions and accept answers that helped you. This is appropriate for the site and also will give you a bit of rep. Afterwards, in the future you can ask more questions by following [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so they will be almost guaranteed to receive positive feedback.